# getting black screen after making outlet of navigation bar of swreavealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner in ios and i am getting black screen after applying title to navigation bar & make outlet of navigation bar of front view of swreavealviewcontroller in xcode 9 before that its working fine so please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up everything related to SWRevealController your storyboard will look like
[image]

Follow the tutorial for more details. [AppCoda tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)